# Fantasy RPG for the Gamecube with an escaped genie

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I don't remember much- Something about a genie escaped from captivity to cause some catastrophe and the hero (player)'s goal was to undo it. I'm fairly certain it was made for the Gamecube, and the commercial for it showed a scene of a minotaur in armour and carrying a battleaxe charging toward the screen.

Comment: Dark Age of Camelot? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7i8_LfIB4o

Comment: @Valorum- I don't think so- what you showed was rendered 'realistically' (for lack of a better word) and the game I seek looked more-animated? cartoonish? Also I think the minotaur in the commercial was more of a disposable bad guy, not a defining character race as your suggestion implies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're describing [Dark Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Cloud), released for the PS2 in 2000/2001, but not ported to the Gamecube.

> Dark Cloud tells the story of a group of adventurers who band together to fight against the Dark Genie, who has attacked and destroyed many villages. The main protagonist and player character is Toan, a boy who is given a magical stone called the Atlamillia by Simba, the Fairy King, granting him the power to rebuild the destroyed lands.

Comment: That looks like it- could've sworn it was made for Nintendo.

Comment: @Nu'Daq Odd, I can't find any reference of a GameCube port, and the game was (at least initially) published by Sony themselves.

Comment: _Dark Cloud_ and its sequel were PS2 exclusives.

Comment: Since asking this, I looked up 'Dark Cloud Minotaur' on Google, got a boss named Minotaur Joe.